# DOM Rendering different with the same url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I recently build my react front end using npm run build to which i got the following folder:

[image: Folder Image]

I copied and pasted all the documents inside my public folder in my nodejs backend

[image: Node Public Folder]

When I start the server it runs well and my Reactjs is rendered as expected via the server.

But Im having an issue:

if i navigate though the page it seems to be working correctly here an example where i go to the /register page

[image]

The problem arises when I try to access the same page but by typing the link localhost:8080/register directly as the page renders completely different:

[image]

I have researched and to my understanding it is due to React-routes don't cause a re render, but I cant find a solution to my problem.

```
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'})
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./routes/db-config.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const cookie = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors')
const port = process.env.PORT

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
  }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors())

db.connect((error)=>{
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log("Connected to DataBase");
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public"))) //Le especifico donde esta mi front end

app.use(morgan('tiny'));



app.use(cookie())
app.use(express.json())



app.use("/",require('./routes/routes.js'))
app.use("/api",require("./controllers/user-auth/auth.js"))
app.use("/gestion-inventario",require("./controllers/gestion-inventarios/Herramienta-Basica/registro_insumos.js"))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

My routes are specified as follows

```
const express = require('express');
const loggedIn = require('../controllers/user-auth/loggedIn.js');
const logout = require('../controllers/user-auth/logout.js');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('./db-config.js');

router.get("/",loggedIn,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.user)
    if(req.user){
        res.send('Hello World! Home')
    } else{
        res.send('Hello World! Home not loggedIn')
    }
})

router.get("/*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendStatus(200)
})



router.get("/gestion-inventario",loggedIn,(req,res)=>{
    if(req.user){
        const {id_Empresa} = req.user
        db.query('SELECT * FROM Inventario_insumos WHERE id_Empresa = ?',[id_Empresa], async (Err,result)=>{
            if(Err) throw Err;
            res.status(200).json({status:"success",success:result})   
        })

    } else{
        res.send('Not loggedIn')
    }
})
```

My reactApp has the following routes

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Error, Login, Dashboard, Register,Landing} from './pages';



function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing/>}/>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>


  );
}

export default App;
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, it's a react-router issue. It has nothing to do with rerenders. It's not pathing correctly. Show us your react-router setup

Comment: Updated the question with react router setup as well as server side setup

Answer (score 0):

After Research I found the following solution https://github.com/jintoppy/react-training/blob/master/basic/node_modules/react-router/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

and incorporated the following code which solved the issue

```
router.get('*', function (request, response){
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public', 'index.html'))})
```